# Hibernates-4.2 -Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError c.C.S.C.D.D.DBConnector.sendQuery.173

Tags: nullpointerexception, sessionfactory, hibernate-4.x, nhibernate-configuration

below is the snippet code from my Java file but after printing label:1 , its giving me exception.

```
           try{
        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("label:1"));

        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration con = new Configuration();

                    logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("label:2"));
        File hiberConfFile=new File("/cfg/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml");
//I am on Unix Env and directory structure is RUN/cfg  and RUN/lib and my java file is in lib dir ,However I have not got any kind of parsing or FileNotfoundException.

        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("label:3"));

        con.configure(hiberConfFile);
               logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("label:4"));


        con.setProperty(USERNAME, dbInfo.getUsername());
        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("UserName:" + con.getProperty(USERNAME)));

        con.setProperty(PASSWORD, dbInfo.getPassword());
        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("PASSWORD:" + con.getProperty(PASSWORD)));

        con.setProperty(URL, ORACLE+dbInfo.getHost()+":"+dbInfo.getPort()+":"+dbInfo.getSid());
        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog("Connection URL:" + con.getProperty(URL)));


        factory =con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = con.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        factory=con.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

         results = session.createQuery(query).list();

        tx.commit();


    }catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.debug(Logger.formatLog(("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex)));
        ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }
```

Getting below Error before creating Configuration Object in Hibernates after Label:1
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError c.C.S.C.D.D.DBConnector.sendQuery.173

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.(Environment.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:300)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:266)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

can anyOne pls help me with this?